# o365 group calendar - schedule meeting in group calendar only

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

I have an O365 group calendar with few participants.

I would like to invite group to a meeting and I want it to be available in group calendar only , so it means that I do not want participant to see meeting invitation in their private calendar but I want to them to see meeting in group calendar only

Is it possible to set up  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most trivial solution would be to create the event in the group calendar without inviting anyone. This way the event is only visible in the group calender.

The cons:

- No invitations
- People with access to the group calendar can still add the event to their private calendar

Comment: is it possibele that group wont auto accept these meetings ? so it wont be visible in participant private calendar ?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what TwinOfLink has replied above, and based on my testing in my lab,  you could see meeting request in participants private calendar if you invite the group as attendee. You only add the event in group calendar directly that the group members cannot see this event in their private calendar till they open group calendar.